# trouble echoing from a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am having trouble getting a variable to pass from the function into the page the function is called on if I writ an echo command in the function itself the variable will echo just fine, but when I echo from the file that I call the function it will not display anything at all. Here are my code examples:

```
//CHECK LOGIN CREDINTIALS
function checkLogin($conn,$myusername, $mypassword, $count) {

       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name`= :userName AND `password`= :userPass');
       $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $myusername);
       $stmt->bindValue(':userPass', $mypassword);
       $stmt->execute();
       $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
       echo "$count<br>";
}
```

Here is the file I am trying to pass the variable from the function into

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
session_is_registered("myusername");
session_is_registered("mypassword");

require 'functions.php';
require 'DB.php';
ob_start();
// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername =$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword =md5($_POST['mypassword']);

checkLogin($conn, $myusername, $mypassword, $count);

echo $count;
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

    $myusername1 = $_SESSION['myusername'];
    //UPDATE LAST LOGIN IN DATABASE
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $last_login = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    lastLogin($conn,$myusername1,$last_login);
    header("location:form.php");


}
else {
echo $count;
echo "$mypassword<br>";
echo "$myusername<br>";
echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
function checkLogin($conn,$myusername, $mypassword) {

       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name`= :userName AND `password`= :userPass');
       $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $myusername);
       $stmt->bindValue(':userPass', $mypassword);
       $stmt->execute();
       $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
       return $count;
}
```

and in your code

```
$myusername =$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword =md5($_POST['mypassword']);
$count=checkLogin($conn,$myusername, $mypassword);
if($count==1){
  //your code
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks can you explain what made this work I seen what you did in the code to make it work but Im curious to know why the method I was using didn't work as intended. I am new to PHP so I am trying to learn as much as possible Ive been working on this problem for a while now lol.

Comment: @Yamaha32088, look at my example carefully, in function `checkLogin`, when it is called it returns `$count`. in next code it is called and assigned the value returned by the function to a variable `$count`. So whatever the function `checkLogin` returns is stored in the variable `$count` in next code.

You did it a wrong way. My code is self explanatory, where did you do wrong please compare your code with mine. for hint the parameters you passed in `checklogin` function is available within the function only.